# Default value with @ParameterObject with Spring

Tags: spring, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

We have an endpoint with a lot of boolean on it, with default values. I wanted to encapsulate those into an object thanks to the `@ParameterObject` annotation.

However, I haven't found a way to set default values for it. My idea was to have something similar to what `@PageableDault` does.

Here the endpoint:

```java
public List<Person> getPersons(@ParameterObject SearchCriteria profileSearchCriteria) {
  // beautiful code
}
```

And here the object (it uses Lombok but shouldn't have an impact I would say :)):

```java
@Builder
@Data
@Jacksonized
public class ProfileSearchCriteria {

    @Builder.Default
    private boolean criteria1 = false;

    @Builder.Default
    private boolean criteria2 = false;

    @Builder.Default
    private boolean criteria3 = false;
```

Do you know how can I setup default values for the `@ParameterObject` annotation?